# Spring Data JPA base repository and multiple entities

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I've got 2 questions regarding Spring Data JPA (3.2) repositories. My background is in .Net c# and recently started using Java, so excuse the lack of knowledge. In .Net we have miro ORMs like Dapper and Petapoco (Npoco) that have a singular database factory, so you can say ".save< MyObjectType >(object)", etc.

I'm seeing with Sprint Data JPA every entity needs it's own repository, which is fine but I was wondering if there was a better (standardized) way of doing this. Below are my questions.

1. Is the connection going to be singular connection since I'm using a "ICrudBaseRepository". So I can reference multiple repositories in a single method (like in "SaveGames" below) and it'll just use the one connection?
2. I understand I've laid things out a bit differently than standard Spring template, but in general I want my Repositories to be like Repository Services, while my actual CRUD Repositories are under "CrudRepositories". Basically I want anything that references a repo (calls the DB) to be abstracted from my service layer. As you can see I'm having to inject each Repository that my "GameRepository" service uses, I'd like to know if theres a better (more standardized) way to handle injecting all those (maybe a way of making a generic wrapper).

Note: I'm aware there are other ORMs like Mybatis, JDBI, etc, but I'm not looking to do any complex DB work and wanted the most modern/standard way of CRUD operations so ended up with spring-data-jpa.

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

[image: File Layout]

[image: ICrudBaseRespository]

[image: ICrudGameRepsitory]

[image: ICrudLevelRepsitory]

[image]

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Is the connection going to be singular connection since I'm using a "ICrudBaseRepository". So I can reference multiple repositories in a single method (like in "SaveGames" below) and it'll just use the one connection?

Yes if you use @Transactional annotation above the method that calls your various repos, it will wrap that all under one transaction (example below). This would indicate to me it's also a singular connection. I don't a base JPA Repository is specifically needed for this, but I used one anyway.

```
public class GameRepository extends BaseRepository implements IGameRepository
{
    private IGameDB _gameDB;
    private ILevelDB _levelDB;

    public GameRepository(IGameDB gameDB, ILevelDB levelDB) {
        _gameDB = gameDB;
        _levelDB = levelDB;
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = { Exception.class })
    public void SaveGames(List<Game> games, List<Level> levels)
    {
        for (Game game : games)
        {
            var gameLevels = levels.stream().filter(x -> x.gameid == game.id).collect(Collectors.toList());
            _levelDB.saveAll(gameLevels);
            _gameDB.save(game);
        }
    }
}
```

2. I understand I've laid things out a bit differently than standard Spring template, but in general I want my Repositories to be like Repository Services, while my actual CRUD Repositories are under "CrudRepositories". Basically I want anything that references a repo (calls the DB) to be abstracted from my service layer. As you can see I'm having to inject each Repository that my "GameRepository" service uses, I'd like to know if theres a better (more standardized) way to handle injecting all those (maybe a way of making a generic wrapper).

I think this design is fine and actually makes sense. Like in the example above you're often going to be calling multiple jpa repositories in one method (like a complex object save). It makes sense to have that layer as the actual "repositories" and then put the jpa repositories in their own folder/namespace. I like that everything that references my database goes from "my repository" layer to the "jpa repository". Below is my layout.

[image: Project Layout]